# why do i need glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

Tags: opengl

here is my code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h> // include GLEW and new version of GL on Windows
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> // GLFW helper library
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    // start GL context and O/S window using the GLFW helper library
    if (!glfwInit ()) {
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW3\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // uncomment these lines if on Apple OS X
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
     glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
     glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
     glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow (640, 480, "Hello Triangle", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: could not open window with GLFW3\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent (window);

    // start GLEW extension handler
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit ();

    // get version info
    const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString (GL_RENDERER); // get renderer string
    const GLubyte* version = glGetString (GL_VERSION); // version as a string
    printf ("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
    printf ("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);

    // tell GL to only draw onto a pixel if the shape is closer to the viewer
    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
    glDepthFunc (GL_LESS); // depth-testing interprets a smaller value as "closer"

    /* OTHER STUFF GOES HERE NEXT */

    float points[] = {
        0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f
    };
    GLuint vbo = 0;
    glGenBuffers (1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof (float), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLuint vao = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays (1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray (vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    const char* vertex_shader =
    "#version 410\n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;"
    "void main () {"
    "  gl_Position = vPosition;"
    "}";
    const char* fragment_shader =
    "#version 410\n"
    "out vec4 frag_colour;"
    "void main () {"
    "  frag_colour = vec4 (0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);"
    "}";
    GLuint vs = glCreateShader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource (vs, 1, &vertex_shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader (vs);
    GLuint fs = glCreateShader (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource (fs, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader (fs);
    GLuint shader_programme = glCreateProgram ();
    glAttachShader (shader_programme, fs);
    glAttachShader (shader_programme, vs);
    glLinkProgram (shader_programme);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose (window)) {
        // wipe the drawing surface clear
        glClear (GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        const GLfloat color[]={0.0,0.2,0.0,1.0};
        //glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR,0,color);
        glUseProgram (shader_programme);
        glBindVertexArray (vao);
        // draw points 0-3 from the currently bound VAO with current in-use shader
        glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        // update other events like input handling
        glfwPollEvents ();
        // put the stuff we've been drawing onto the display
        glfwSwapBuffers (window);
    }    // close GL context and any other GLFW resources
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

when i comment line glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT),the window showing up did not display anything,does this routine matter?
i am using Xcode and Mac OS X 10.1.2,please help me with this ,thanks

Comment: you should really _read_ the comments in your own code.

Answer (score 13):

The depth buffer is used to decide if geometry you render is closer to the viewer than geometry you rendered previously. This allows the elimination of hidden geometry.

This test is executed per fragment (pixel). Any time a fragment is rendered, its depth is compared to the corresponding value in the depth buffer. If the new depth is bigger, the fragment is eliminated by the depth test. Otherwise, the fragment is written to the color buffer, and the value in the depth buffer is updated with the depth of the new fragment. The functionality is controlled by these calls you make during setup:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
```

This way, if a fragment is covered by multiple triangles, the color of the final pixels will be given by the geometry that was closest to the viewer.

Now, if you don't clear the depth buffer at the start of each frame, the comparison to the value in the depth buffer described above will use whatever value happens to be in the depth buffer. This could be a value from a previous frame, or an uninitialized garbage value. Therefore, fragments can be eliminated by the depth test even though no fragments in the current frame were drawn at the same position before. In the extreme case, all fragments are eliminated by the depth test, and you see nothing at all.

Unless you are certain that you will render something to all pixels in your window, you will also want to clear the color buffer at the start of the frame. So your clear call should be:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

// wipe the drawing surface clear
        , glClear (GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

What that comment means above the code means is that it clears the depth buffer. The depth buffer is the part of the frame buffer, that makes objects being obstructed by other objectsin front of them. Without clearing the depth buffer, you'd draw into the depth structure of the previous drawing.